# SSMS 2008 indent on line break

Tags: ssms

I'm tired of using <kbd>Tab</kbd> key when I pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Tab</kbd> Key in SSMS editor because when I have something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Example
BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON

        SET DATEFORMAT MDY
```

If the caret is after the *SET NOCOUNT ON* sentence and then I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the caret position goes to the beginning of the next line instead of doing two <kbd>Tabs</kbd>.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have Block indenting turned on for T-SQL files:

- In the Tools menu select Options.
- In the options window expand the "Text Editor" node and the "Transact-SQL" node to select the "Tabs" node.
- Ensure Indenting is set to "Block"